# TypeError When Adding another value to GeoJsonToolTip

Tags: python, geojson, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to make a map with the number of noise complaints for each zipcode and everything runs fine, but I can't get the count number to appear on the map when I hover over each area. I tried making it into an `int` as the error suggested, but nothing seems to work.

```
import pandas as pd

df2020 = pd.read_csv('/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI 233 Seminar Project/311_Noise_Complaints.csv',sep=',', low_memory = False)
df2020=df2020[df2020['Created Date'].str[6:10] == '2020']
    
df2020['Incident Zip'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df2020['Incident Zip'] = df2020['Incident Zip'].astype(int)
df2020_zip = df2020['Incident Zip'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
df2020_zip.columns = ['postal_code', 'counts']
df2020_zip['postal_code'] = df2020_zip['postal_code'].astype(str)
df2020_zip['counts'] = df2020_zip['counts'].astype(int)

        
import folium

nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.693943, -73.985880], zoom_start=10)
zipLines = '/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI 233 Seminar Project/zipMap.geojson.json'
df2020_zip['counts'] = df2020_zip['counts'].astype(int)
df2020_zip['counts'] = pd.Series(zipLines['counts'])
count_col = df2020_zip['counts']


bins = list(df2020_zip['counts'].quantile([0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1]))
choropleth = folium.Choropleth(geo_data = zipLines,
                           data=df2020_zip,
                           columns=['postal_code', 'counts'],
                           key_on='feature.properties.postalCode',
                           fill_color='OrRd',
                           fill_opacity=0.7,
                           line_opacity=1.0,
                           bins = bins,
                           highlight=True,
                           legend_name="Noise Frequency in 2020"
                           ).add_to(nycMap)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(nycMap)
choropleth.geojson.add_child(
    folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['postalCode','PO_NAME','count_col'])
)
nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/throwaway.py", line 20, in <module>
    df2020_zip['counts'] = pd.Series(zipLines['counts'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Dataset: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Noise-Complaints/p5f6-bkga

Zipcode GeoJson: https://data.beta.nyc/dataset/nyc-zip-code-tabulation-areas/resource/6df127b1-6d04-4bb7-b983-07402a2c3f90?view_id=b34c6552-9fdb-4f95-8810-0588ad1a4cc8

Comment: Hello @user13451867. This is a continuation of the last issue. Is the data you are using the same as the previous CSV and JSON? With the data I answered last time, when I apply it with this code, I get a different error and cannot confirm your error.

Comment: Hi @r-beginners yea, I'm using the same dataset. I've been playing around with the code and am getting a new error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/x/Desktop/throwaway.py", line 21, in <module>
    df2020_zip['counts'] = pd.Series(int(zipLines['counts']))
TypeError: string indices must be integers`.  I edited the original post to show the new lines of code. ( I tried doing something similar to what you suggested to me in another question)

Comment: Just in case, why don't you provide a link between CSV and JSON? This will have the effect of increasing the number of respondents other than me. Also, the title is in the old error, so you should fix that.

Comment: `pd.Series(zipLines['count']`What is this code for? Isn't it a mistake for `df2020_zip['counts']`?

Comment: `folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['postalCode','PO_NAME','count_col'])`Here, we need the item names in GeoJson, and no `count_col`.

Comment: for the `pd.series` code that was my attempt at adding the counts columns from the first df to the zipLines data frame so that I could add it to the `GeoJsonTooltip` code. In one of my attempts I got the error code: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid` so I tried that line from a question similar question that was posted on this site.

Comment: This is a fundamental issue, but if there is no frequency of occurrence data in the GeoJson file, it cannot be displayed in the tooltip. The 'counts' in the user data is used to paint the map. Also, the zip code in the user data is linked to the 'postalCode' in the GeoJson file and displayed on the map.

Comment: So there's no other way for me to share the values from 'counts' with the GeoJson file? From what I've read so far, it seemed possible to add a column from one df to a second one.

Comment: I looked it up and it looks like you can specify the value you want to tooltip. I referred to [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/interactive-choropleth-map-in-python-using-folium-4e1479d9e568).

Comment: I can't access the article, but I decided to just leave the counts out because it was more of a preference thing and wasn't necessary for what I had to do, I'll have to look further into this on my own time. But thanks anyway! And thanks for answering all my questions before this (you saved me tons!)